# Maximum value of $|f(z)|$

Tags: complex-analysis, analytic-functions

Today while Reading maximum modulus theorem I encountered this question!

**Question**: find the maximum value $|f(z)|$ in $|z|≤1$ for the function $f(z)=\frac{2z+1}{2z-1}$

But, how we can apply maximum modulus theorem to above function? As it is clear that, $f(z)$ is not analytic at $z= 1/2$ which lies inside $|z|≤1$ :-(

So how one can find maximum value for the given function? Please help me, stuck on this!

Comment: The maximum value of $|f(z)|$ does not exist.

Comment: As you say, there is no maximum: $\lim_{z\to 1/2} |f(z)|=+\infty$

Comment: @i707107 Sir, maximum value does not exists because, as function has pole at $z=1/2$ and so it's limit tends to $∞$ at $z=1/2$ is am I correct?

Answer (score 1):

The limit does not exist at z = 1/2 because the left limit does not equal the right limit there. I think all you can say is that the function approaches its max value as z approaches 1/2 from the right.